# How to desaturate the image in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, scikit-image

I was going through a code of converting gray images to colored images, but before doing that, code converts the input image to desaturated image with the help of given line of code :

```
def load_image(path):
    img = imread(path)
    # crop image from center
    short_edge = min(img.shape[:2])
    yy = int((img.shape[0] - short_edge) / 2)
    xx = int((img.shape[1] - short_edge) / 2)
    crop_img = img[yy : yy + short_edge, xx : xx + short_edge]
    # resize to 224, 224
    img = skimage.transform.resize(crop_img, (224, 224))
    # desaturate image
    return (img[:,:,0] + img[:,:,1] + img[:,:,2]) / 3.0
```

I am getting error in this particular line, error read as:

```
return (img[:,:,0] + img[:,:,1] + img[:,:,2]) / 3.0
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Please help me with the problem i am facing.

Comment: What are those commas for?

Comment: I have no clue about that, runs fine for given picture but produces above mentioned error for the rest.

Comment: Because the others are legitimate 2D arrays that you are trying to access with a 3D index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to desaturate an image.  Please use `skimage.color.rgb2gray`, which can be applied to 2D images (that are already desaturated) without any problem.

I.e., change the last line to:

```
return color.rgb2gray(img)
```

and add `from skimage import color` earlier in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code will work with either a 2D (grayscale) or a 3D (RGB) array. However, the last line explicitly requires a 3D array. You can add a conditional to pass through 2D arrays since the code is just averaging the channels together:

```
if img.ndim < 3:
    return img
# return average
```

Alternatively, you can raise a more informative error at the start of the function as soon as you realize you have a 2D array. Do whatever makes sense.